# How to specify target architecture in quickly apps?

Tags: application-development, quickly, architecture

I'm building a quickly-app, Do I have to specify somewhere the architecture (amd64,i386,etc) in which my app can run?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly